# applying a freeze transformation command to several duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates, maya

I try to apply a freeze transformation command as well as deleting the history of my duplicates of a geo sphere in maya. Unfortunately it just gets applied to the first object. Here is my forloop:

```
for items in rigSelection:


    cmds.listRelatives(shapes=True)


    cleanDuplicate = cmds.duplicate(rigSelection, name= str(items) + str(cleanGeo))   


    conDuplicate = cmds.duplicate(rigSelection, name= str(items) + str(conGeo))


    for cleaner in items: 

        cmds.delete(constructionHistory=True)

        cmds.makeIdentity(apply=True, t=1, r=1, s=1, n=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your duplicates are under cleanDuplicate/conDuplicate. You should loop throught them and use command in for loop like this :

```
items = cleanDuplicate + conDuplicate # where cleanDuplicate/conDuplicate are []
for cleaner in items: 
    cmds.delete(cleaner, constructionHistory=True)
    cmds.makeIdentity(cleaner, apply=True, t=1, r=1, s=1, n=0)
```